# Print one random answer out of six

Tags: java, swing

My code is printing out multiple answers when I only want one at a time, could you help me to have it only print one at a time?

I would also like help so that when it runs, there is a button you can press that will refresh the page producing a new question, out of the six anyway.

```
package ScienceRevision;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Image extends JFrame {


    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 30 );
    public Image(){

        //Game Properties
        setTitle("WheelOP");
        //setSize(750, 750);
        setResizable(false);

        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }




    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);

        Random rand = new Random();
        int result = rand.nextInt(6);
        if (result == 0){
        g.drawString("Cell Wall Definition", 100, 100 );
        }
        else if (result == 1){
        g.drawString("Vacuole Definition", 100, 100 );
        }
        else if (result == 2){
        g.drawString("Choroplast Definition", 100, 100 );
        }
        else if (result == 3){
        g.drawString("Nucleus Definition", 100, 100 );
        }
        else if (result == 4){
        g.drawString("Cell Membrane Definition", 100, 100 );
        }
        else if (result == 5){
        g.drawString("Cytoplasm Definition", 100, 100 );
        }
}





    public void paintcomponent (Graphics g){

}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame jframe = new Image();
        jframe.setSize(750,750);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `JFrame.setSize` will invoke the `paint` method. Set the size after you initialize and remove it from your constructor.

```
//Game Properties
setTitle("WheelOP");
//setSize(750, 750);
setResizable(false);
setVisible(true);
setBackground(Color.CYAN);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame image = new Image();
        image.setSize(750,750);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
You also should be setting your background color to the content pane not the actual frame. And we should set it visible after doing all of that.  So it would look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame jframe = new Image();
    jframe.setSize(750,750);
    jframe.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: It is still painting multiple answers at a time.

Comment: Did you remove both `setSize(750, 750);` and `setVisible(true);` from the constructor?

Comment: Yes.       public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame jframe = new Image();
        jframe.setSize(750,750);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }

Comment: Hey @DevonPayne, I'm not able to reproduce the error. Can you update your question with the most up to date code with all the changes so I can see how you have everything set up with the new changes?

Comment: @DevonPayne I am only getting one answer to print, even with using your exact code. I am not sure what the issue is. Hopefully someone else will join in on the conversation. Sorry I could not be more helpful.

Comment: Hello, the issue is that when I run it it's fine, then if i close it and run again it prints  a new answer over the previous.

Comment: @DevonPayne I just ran it 5 times in a row, with your code and still only get one answer to print. Do you know what java version you are running?

Comment: Hello, I am on Java 8 I think, using eclipse.